# Is it possible to relocate the mount point of a btrfs subvolume within the same root?

Tags: mount, btrfs

I have created a btrfs subvolume in the path of /docker/nc/data. As shown below:

```
$ sudo btrfs subvolume list /
ID 256 gen 13908 top level 5 path docker
ID 257 gen 13877 top level 256 path docker/nc/data
```

Is it possible to move the subvolume somewhere within the subvolume docker? I.e.

```
/docker/nc/config/data
```

There are nearly 90GiB of data in it. Is it possible to be done without copying?

Comment: Feel free to use the `mv` command.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please clarify. Show what is mounted and where `findmnt`. And explain what is being moved where.

Comment: Sorry for being confusing.

I mean permanently moving the subvolume located in `/docker/nc/data` to mount at a new location, `/docker/nc/config/data`.